# HTML форма регистрации

Tags: java, html, css

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Есть форма регистрации.
[image: Есть форма регистрации]

HTML

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="yourpage.html">
    <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off" id="name">
    <div>
        <p class="name-help">Please enter your first and last name.</p>
    </div>

    <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" autocomplete="off">
    <div>
        <p class="email-help">Please enter your current email address.</p>
    </div>

    <%--<input type="password" class="name" placeholder="Password" id="password" autocomplete="off">--%>
    <%--<div>--%>
        <%--<p class="name-help">Please enter your password.</p>--%>
    <%--</div>--%>

    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

если убрать коммент с пасворда, то получается это
[image: форма с пассвордом]

Собственно вопрос: почему имайл переквалифицировался (самостоятельно) в юзер, почему на эти два инпута не действует CSS, почему это так происходит и как это можно исправить?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Какое отношение к вопросу имеет тег java?

Comment: Чтобы появилась надпись user, должен быть атрибут placeholder="user", а его я не наблюдаю. Вероятно ваша форма генерируется процедурно и надо искать ошибку в генерирующем её скрипте.

Comment: Если я меняю input type на text вместо password, то тогда ок, только вводимый пароль не заменяется точками.

Comment: непробовали реализовать через javascript?